# Sweet alert closing on spacebar press.

Tags: sweetalert

I have a sweet alert with a textarea on it, the window is closing on spacebar press.

```
 swal({
            title: 'Something Went Wrong',
            text: '<textarea id="my-textarea" name="my-textarea" rows="5" />',
            type: 'error',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Refresh Page',
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
            html: true
        }
```

Can I prevent this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved it like this :
If you use le min js, retrieve this part of code in sweet-alert.min.js "**=n.keyCode||n.which,a=k(m,"visible");if(-1!==[9,13**" and remove the next "**32**" in the array which represant the ascii code of spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

I have comment line 388 and was able to have the window not closing.

```
//fireClick($targetElement, e);
```