# Sweet alert 2 closing when pressing space bar with Froala editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, froala, sweetalert2

Currently I am creating a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) that displays a [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) HTML editor, This is done in a function called CreatePolicyPopUp (which is triggered on a button click). However, when I press the space bar inside the editor it closes the sweet alert. Previously I was using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for the html editor but this problem did not happen.

This is a stripped down version of the code that creates the sweet alert and initializes the editor.

```
CreatePolicyPopUp: function (fromTemplate, duplicatePolicyID, allVals) {
        $.get("CreatePolicy.html", function (data) {
            swal({
                html: data,
                showCloseButton: false,
                showCancelButton: false,
                width: 800,
                showConfirmButton: false
            }).then(function () {

            });

            /*initialize editor*/
            $('#froalatextarea').froalaEditor();

        });
    },
```

Could there be anything conflicting between froala and sweetalert2?
Or is there a way to disable close on pressing the space bar?

If needed here is the html for my [CreatePolicy.html](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/42xLpd8z/) file and also the whole CreatePolicyPopUp function is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684404/sweet-alert-closing-on-spacebar-press) post I found with a similar problem on an old version of sweetalert. I found out that the sweet alert 2 plugin is listening out for a space key pressed using charactercodes (the space charcode is 32) so to fix it I removed the space bar character from the close sweet alert event.

The easiest way to remove this in the sweetalert2.min.js file was to find "||32===r" and delete it.